# Why the firebase auth StreamBuilder navigate to the HomePage only when an existing user login, but doesn't navigate when a new user sign up in the app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have the following:

`

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final User? user = snapshot.data;

          if (user == null) {
            return Login();
          }
          return HomePage();
        }

        return Login();
      },
    );
```

`**Problem:** when try to login with an existing user email and password, the stream builder move me to the`HomePage`normall as expected, but when I try to sign up with a new user email and password, it created fine in the firebase console, but the screen doesn't change to the`HomePage`.

when I debug to what happens, after I sign up, the ``user`is not null as you see here:`
[image]

but it just don't open the `HomePage`.

any ideas, or I'm missing something ?

I'm expecting that if the user login or sign up, the `HomePage` should opens.
and I want to know why the login works fine, but signing up just don't do nothing

Answer (score 1):

Where did you print "user is not null as you see here:"?

Are you sure the Stream event gets triggered?

If not after user registered try to add this line and see if Stream gets triggered!

```
await user.reload();
```

Comment: Hi, yes I'm sure the stream triggers when the user is logged in, as you see in the debug image I provided when logged in and sign up, the user has data, but it shows the homepage only when I log in, when I sign up no action happens

Comment: Try to reload user after he registered as I wrote in my answer and see if Stream gets triggered